# A general theory of representation of algebraic structures

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Often algebraic objects like groups or monoids could be represented in terms of other objects, in the case of groups as automorphisms for example of graphs, or as permutations (automorphisms of a finite sets), or of some vector space. Is there a general theory about these representations? When could we switch between them (for example representing permutations by matrices, and elements by a basis vector representing characteristic vectors). Is there a general notion of "isomorphism" between different representations, how to capture abstractly the notion of an representation? Guess it might have to do with category theory? But then, does this theory just works in case of associative algebraic structures?

And could this theory in some sense capture the "richness" of a representation, for example a matrix representation I would consider more "rich" as a permutation representation, as when computing with vectors and matrices more could be done, or more laws hold.

Comment: Tannakian categories and Grothendieck's Galois Theory come to my mind, but I don't even know enough about them to assess whether they would fit what you're looking for. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannakian_formalism

Comment: You could say for a category $\mathcal{C}$, that a representation of a group $G$ in $\mathcal{C}$ is a group homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(X)$ for some object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$. Permutation representations is when $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of sets. Linear representations is when $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of vector spaces, etc...

Comment: @Nick yes, that make it more specific, but on top of that how to relate these representations, defining some kinds of isomorphisms between them...